# Make your iOS device work like an IP-cam? (Remote video watching)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, applications, camera

I would like to use my iPad to record video (or even taking continuous photos every few seconds would be fine), and while it is recording, i would like to be able to see the video from my iPhone.

What I'm trying to do is to leave the iPad at home, and take the iPhone outside to watch what the iPad is recording at home.

I guess I'm trying to have the iPad work like an ip-surveillance camera.
I don't necessarily have to use the pre-installed Camera app if there is another app that can do this (the camera app eats up lots of storage space quickly anyways).

If anyone know how to do this, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  There are many apps in the AppStore that do exactly what you appear to be asking...one good search is "security camera".

Answer (score 1):

I use an app that works pretty well for turning a spare iDevice into a security camera and monitoring that feed on another iDevice. It's called "Presence" It's free with IAPs, but I've never paid a dime and it works fine for me. You will need to make an account with them, though.